# Signal protocol: when, and why, is X3DH run again between the same two users?

Tags: diffie-hellman, protocol-design, key-exchange, signal-protocol

This question concerns the Signal protocol's X3DH key agreement protocol as documented [here](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/).

Obviously, if Alice and Bob have never contacted each other before, they need to run X3DH at least once to agree on a key.

However, it is unclear to me why X3DH needs to be run more than once between the same two users: now that they have agreed on a key, and given the Double Ratchet algorithm is used to generate new keys for each message to ensure perfect forward secrecy, why would they ever need to run X3DH again?

Without the need to run a key agreement protocol a second time between the same two users, a simple DH between Alice and Bob's identity keys should suffice, and perfect forward secrecy is not an issue since the protocol would never be run again. Only if the protocol needs to be run more than once would X3DH be called for, to restore perfect forward secrecy.

I imagine this is due to an implementation decision of not committing any keys beyond the bare minimum (private keys for the identity key, signed prekey and one-time prekeys) to non-volatile storage, so that when the app is restarted, the protocol would need to be run again. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Signal has an option for chats called "restart secure session". I'm pretty sure this is what would trigger 3DH to run again. The threat model here would be a leak of the ratchet key, but no leak of the long term identity key.

Comment: @Natanael would you happen to know if, unless this option is triggered, X3DH is never run again?

Comment: Not certain. I do believe Signal retains the ratchet key until any of the asymmetric keys involved are replaced (reinstall, etc). A change of long term identity key always trigger a new key exchange. In typical scenarios, the long term identity key and the ratchet key can be assumed to have approximately equal threat models and protection (stored in the same app database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is unclear to me why X3DH needs to be run more than once

They don't. `X3DH` is only used to initialise the session between Alice amd Bob. Once **`Root key`** is derived, X3DH is no longer required until one of them reinstalls the app or changes device.

Together with `Diffie Hellman ratchet`,  using `KDF`

- `Root key` derives **`Chain key`** and `Root key` is updated.
- `Chain key` derives **`Message key`** and `Chain key` is updated.

`Message key` is the one which encrypts the message. For every subsequent message, `Chain key` is updated to derive new `Message key`.

The process looks something like this:

[image: Double Ratchet]

**`A1`** and **`B1`** are `Message keys`.

Even though the session is not reinitialised periodically, [Signal documentation](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/sesame/#session-expiration) actually recommends this but currently it is not used in practice by either WhatsApp or Signalapp.

> **4.2. Session expiration**
>   It may be desirable for devices to periodically replace old sessions with new sessions, for security purposes.

However, long-term keys of the prekey bundle are still rotated but are not reinitialised with the current recipients.

```
// Time before rotation of signed prekeys (measured in seconds)
//
// Currently we rotate signed prekeys every 2 days (48 hours).
// We generate 100 one-time prekeys at a time.  We should
replenish
// whenever ~2/3 of them have been consumed.
```

[Source](https://github.com/signalapp/SignalServiceKit/blob/master/src/Account/TSPreKeyManager.m#L20)

**`Identity key`** is kept same unless the app is reinstalled or the device is changed.

As [@Natanael](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/7431/natanael), Signal has an option to restart secure session which reintialises **X3DH**. There is also a [multi-device](https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/articles/360007320551-Linked-Devices) support in Signal which reintialises X3DH between the recepient and the device. It only happens once with each new device until the app is reinstalled.